# when tried popstate function its not working on React, how to trigger browser backtab click once confirmed logout button modal showed but won't

Tags: javascript, reactjs, logout, browser-tab

When broser back Tab clicked after, React posState function to confirm logout function how i trigger.

how to implement React application when i triggered back tab, its once confirmed in modal ok button to logout application.

```
const handlePopState = event =>{
       console.log(event)
      }
      useEffect(() => {
        window.addEventListener('popstate', handlePopState);
        return () => {
          window.removeEventListener('popstate', handlePopState);
        };
      }, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use createBrowserHistory.
Here is the example code.

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from "history";

...
const browserHistory = createBrowserHistory();
useEffect(() => {
    browserHistory.listen((update) => {
      if (update.action === "POP") console.log("Backbutton pressed");
    });
  }, []);
...
```

Comment: useEffect(() => {
    browserHistory.listen((update, event) => {
      if (update.action === "POP") {
        console.log("Backbutton pressed");
        history.go(1);
      }
    });
  }, []);     used this code it rendered
1. first (2) times rendered
2. second (4) times rendered